# Attribute routing with parameter is not working: Without Parameter is working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, routes

I am working on Asp.Net MVC 5 Web API project with Attribute routing. I have a country controller with RoutePrefix and Route applied. If I do make a request for a method without parameter or method with a model as the parameter, it works fine.

For example, I make a request for

`AddorEdit` Method using `Country model` from `http://localhost/api/Master/Country/AddOrEdit`,

and

`GetAll` method from `http://localhost/api/Master/Country/GetAll`

this work and return the result.

however, If I call a method with the string parameter, it does not work.
for example,

If I make a call to

`Get/{transId}` from `http://localhost/api/Master/Country/Get/1`

`Get/{transId}` from `http://localhost/api/Master/Country/Get/?transId=1`

`Get/{transId}` from `http://localhost/api/Master/Country/Get?transId=1`,

this does not work. This produce the below error:

```
<Error>
    <Message>
         No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:11035/api/Master/Country/Get/449cc9b8-81b3-4b7e-8561-b98cf39d9492'.
    </Message>
    <MessageDetail>
         No action was found on the controller 'Country' that matches the request.
    </MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

I have also checked using the HTTP Verbs and applied the 2 verbs. Also, make the `POST` request from Postman, but still receiving the same error.

I have tried to google and SO but no luck. I have also added the Default Routing rule still no luck.

Routing Code

```
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{transId}",
                defaults: new { transId = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Controller Code

```
    [RoutePrefix("api/Master/Country")]
    public class CountryController : BaseApiController
    {
        [Route("AddOrEdit")]
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult AddOrEdit(Country country)
        {
            try
            {
                using (ApplicationDbContext dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext())
                {
                    var _country = dbContext.Country.Where(x => x.TransID.Equals(country.TransID)).FirstOrDefault();

                    if(null == _country)
                        dbContext.Country.Add(country);
                    else
                    {
                        _country.Code = country.Code;
                        _country.Name = country.Name;
                        _country.Description = country.Description;
                        _country.IsDeleted = country.IsDeleted;
                    }

                    dbContext.SaveChanges();
                }

                return Ok();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return InternalServerError(e);
            }
        }


        [Route("Get/{ transId }")]
        [HttpGet, HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult GetCountryResult(string transId)
        {
            Country data;

            try
            {
                using (ApplicationDbContext dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext())
                {
                    data = dbContext.Country
                        .Where(x => x.TransID.Equals(new Guid(transId)))
                        .FirstOrDefault();
                }

                return Ok(data);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return InternalServerError(e);
            }
        }


        [Route("GetAll")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult GetCountryResults()
        {
            List<Country> lidata;

            try
            {
                using (ApplicationDbContext dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext())
                {
                    lidata = dbContext.Country.ToList();
                }

                return Ok(lidata);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return InternalServerError(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try removing the extra spaces at transId in route
eg:
insted of this `[Route("Get/{ transId }")]` try this `[Route("Get/{transId}")]`

check out the route differences

`[Route("Get/{ transId }")]`
[image]

`[Route("Get/{transId}")]`
[image]

```
  [Route("Get/{transId}")]
    [HttpGet, HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult GetCountryResult(string transId)
    {
        Country data;

        try
        {
            using (ApplicationDbContext dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                data = dbContext.Country
                    .Where(x => x.TransID.Equals(new Guid(transId)))
                    .FirstOrDefault();
            }

            return Ok(data);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return InternalServerError(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @arvind, Thanks for the solution. It works. Kinda dumb the braces things. Lol!